# React state not clearing when component refreshes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

In my redux store I have 4 arrays of objects, in the code below you will see I check if a certain prop is set, then if so, I dispatch these 4 arrays. I then use different useEffects to transform them and amalgamate them into the state (to populate a datatable). All of this works fine, however if I leave the page and return to it, the operation runs again and I have 2 of everything. the initial value of my state is `[]`. I have tried dispatching a reset reducer to set them all back to empty arrays but the previous state still remains.

```
useEffect(() => {
        if(props.contractor._id) {
            dispatch({ type: INCOMING_CALLS_LIST_RESET })
            dispatch({ type: OUTGOING_CALLS_LIST_RESET })
            dispatch({ type: MEETING_LIST_RESET })
            dispatch({ type: EMAIL_LIST_RESET })
            dispatch(listIncomingCalls())
            dispatch(listOutgoingCalls())
            dispatch(listMeetings())
            dispatch(listEmails())
        }
    }, [props.contractor._id, dispatch])

    useEffect(() => {
        if(incCalls) {
            const transformedIncomingCalls = incCalls.filter(call => call.contractor._id === props.contractor._id).map(c => ({
                type: 'Incoming Call',
                contact_person: c.contact_person,
                logged_by: c.created_by.name,
                date: <Moment format="DD/MM/YYYY @ HH:SS">
                        {c.time_created}
                        </Moment>,
                link: <> <LinkContainer to={`/incoming-calls/${c._id}`} className='text-success' style={{ cursor: 'pointer'}}><Eye /></LinkContainer> </>
            }))
            setData(prevData => [...prevData, ...transformedIncomingCalls])
        }
    }, [incCalls, props.contractor._id])

    useEffect(() => {
        if(outCalls) {
            const transformedOutgoingCalls = outCalls.filter(call => call.contractor._id === props.contractor._id).map(c => ({
                type: 'Outgoing Call',
                contact_person: c.contact_person,
                logged_by: c.created_by.name,
                date: <Moment format="DD/MM/YYYY @ HH:SS">
                {c.time_created}
            </Moment>,
                link: <> <LinkContainer to={`/outgoing-calls/${c._id}`} className='text-success' style={{ cursor: 'pointer'}}><Eye /></LinkContainer> </>
            }))
            setData(prevData => [...prevData, ...transformedOutgoingCalls])
        }
    }, [outCalls, props.contractor._id])

    useEffect(() => {
        if(meetings_list) {
            const transformedMeetings = meetings_list.filter(meeting => meeting.contractor._id === props.contractor._id).map(m => ({
                type: 'Meeting',
                contact_person: m.held_with,
                logged_by: m.logged_by.name,
                date: <Moment format="DD/MM/YYYY @ HH:SS">
                {m.meeting_time}
            </Moment>,
                link: <> <LinkContainer to={`/meeting/${m._id}`} className='text-success' style={{ cursor: 'pointer'}}><Eye /></LinkContainer> </>
            }))
            setData(prevData => [...prevData, ...transformedMeetings])
        }
    }, [meetings_list, props.contractor._id])

    useEffect(() => {
        if(email_list) {
            const transformedEmails = email_list.filter(email => email.contractor._id === props.contractor._id).map(e => ({
                type: 'Email',
                contact_person: e.contact_person,
                logged_by: e.logged_by.name,
                date: <Moment format="DD/MM/YYYY @ HH:SS">
                {e.date}
            </Moment>,
                link: <> <LinkContainer to={`/emails/${e.contractor._id}/`} className='text-success' style={{ cursor: 'pointer'}}><Eye /></LinkContainer> </>
            }))
            setData(prevData => [...prevData, ...transformedEmails])
        }
    }, [email_list, props.contractor._id])
```

Comment: Have you tried dispatching those resets on unmount (useEffect return function)?

Comment: Could you offer a code snippet so I can fully understand? I have 5 useEffects

Comment: Assuming that the meetings_list etc. are the whole new meetings etc., you might want to consider having the data as object so that adding data with existing ids will  overwrite instead of append duplicates. The object structure could be for instance {[contract_id]: {[type]: {...}, ...}}

Comment: This is a cleanup function example to clean up state on unmount: 
  `const [isOnline, setIsOnline] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => { 
    setIsOnline(true) 
    return () => setIsOnline(false) // this is run on unmount 
  }`
More info: [Official docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)

Comment: It should be enough to have the cleanup in just one useEffect

Comment: It doesn't work unfortunately